# Show & Hide Div When Scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

My question has been partly answered in this thread - [Show Div when scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097501/show-div-when-scroll-position), but I would like to know:

1)How to show and hide the Div based on scrolling up or down. A specific example is this website which shows/hids the Div based on scrolling up or down and also has them fade in from the left or right - http://bit.ly/1lOZXRY.

2) How do you achieve the effect of automatically scrolling down the website like a story is being told when you click "Click here to read the story..."?

Thanks you :)

Comment: Use the previous scroll position against the new scroll position to determine if it is a negative or positive number. Negative means scrolling up (towards top of the page from the bottom), positive means scrolling down from top to bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your help user887515. What about the fade in and fade out effects from the left and right, and the automatic scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Jquery plugin doing what you want [Scrollmagic](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/)

One example do exactly what you wanted [anchor link](http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/examples/advanced/anchor_link_scrolling.html)
To change the scroll duration just change the *tweenmax*

```
TweenMax.to(window, 2.5, {scrollTo: {y: $elem.offset().top}}); //line 79
```