# Triggering an event as soon as the element is scrolled on to the screen

Tags: jquery, html, animation, parallax

I have an element with the id `ig-container`. I want to add classes like

```
$("#ig-container").addClass("animated bounceInRight");
```

to that element as soon it is visible on the screen. By doing this I can achieve an animation on that element when the user scrolls over that element.

How would I do this?

PS: I tried using .is(":visible") but it did not work as I wanted since this checks whether the element is present in DOM.

Comment: look here, sounds sensible to me

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097501/show-div-when-scroll-position

Comment: Or you can use libraries like [onScreen()](http://silvestreh.github.io/onScreen/) or [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

example of my own here, make sure you use doctype otherwise $(window).height() returns document height

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(window).scroll(function(){

                if(($('.diff').offset().top+$('.diff').height()) < ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()))
                {    
                    $('.diff').addClass('green');
                }
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style>
            .green { background:#0F0 !important; }
        </style>    

    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="min-height:250px; margin-bottom:10px; background:#F00;">1</div>
        <div style="min-height:250px; margin-bottom:10px; background:#F00;">2</div>
        <div style="min-height:250px; margin-bottom:10px; background:#F00;">3</div>
        <div style="min-height:250px; margin-bottom:10px; background:#F00;">4</div>
        <div class="diff" style="min-height:250px; margin-bottom:10px; background:#00F;">THIS ONE</div>
        <div style="min-height:250px; margin-bottom:10px; background:#F00;">1</div>
        <div style="min-height:250px; margin-bottom:10px; background:#F00;">1</div>
        <div style="min-height:250px; margin-bottom:10px; background:#F00;">1</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

scroll slowly and you should see that as soon as you are passed the blue div it changes to green

hope it helps

tomhre