# Showing an element when visible with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does the `+ 1` means in this example?
In this statement: `if ($('.hideme').index($(this)) + 1 === $('.hideme').length)`

http://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/1151/

It's from the answer of one of the questions here, on stackoverflow:
[Show Div when scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097501/show-div-when-scroll-position)

Comment: It adds one to `$('.hideme').index($(this))` and compares it to `$('.hideme').length`.

Comment: Do you really mean, why is the +1 needed? Because as to what +1 "means", well, it adds one.

Comment: Yes, I meant what is it needed for

Comment: Why the water is wet? I think he ment Why is he adding 1 not What the code means.

Comment: length show count of elements, but numbering began from zero, 10 elements with 0 - 9 indexes, length return 10, index return index of element in array (9 + 1 === 10)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`index` starts from Zero, and the `length` Property for a non-empty element starts from 1.

Jquery `index` method Searches for a given element from among the matched elements.

From [Jquery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

> If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an
>   integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery
>   object relative to the elements matched by the selector. If the
>   element is not found,  .index() will return -1.

In most Programming languages, the index starts from 0. So, the index returned would be always 1 less than the actual number.

Comment: Thanks! I got it now

Answer (score 0):

It's to do with how we number elements in programming.
When counting in arrays we start from 0

```
<div></div> 0
<div></div> 1
<div></div> 2
<div></div> 3
<div></div> 4
```

However, if you want to know how many there are there are 5. So you can add 1 to the answer to get the correct result count